# Can i use a chord scale in key signature like CDEFGABC: A CHORD SCALE

Tags: theory, chords, scales, acoustic-guitar

To play a song in key is there a possibility of playing a scale of chord in key signature. For example c major key CDEFGABC: In this A is the major 6, can i use A major scale A,B,C#,D,E,F#,G#,A with chord progression C,E,A

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's going to be quite dissonant, because there are going to be a lot of notes clashing. The A major scale has C# and G# whereas the chord C has C and G natural.* So, those notes are going to create a dissonance. It will sound smoothly over the E and A chords, because E is the V of A, so the notes are the same.

Keep in mind that the chord progression `C,E,A` isn't part of the C major scale. It borrows chords from other scales (or secondary dominants, I'm not sure where the progression is going). So, you wouldn't stick to the C major scale to play over.

*If you like this kind of dissonance, go for it. Also, it depends on the style of music you're going to be playing this. Not all of them want this dissonance, but if it's your composition, you are free to try them out.

Comment: I am beginner i need some guidance. so usually do i have to select only of signature notes rather chord scales.

Comment: @Y07 I updated my answer a bit. The A major scale will sound nice over the E and A chords, but not so nice over the C chord

Answer (score 1):

When you are on a certain chord for a bar, then, yes, it'll work. I presume a bar of C, using C scale notes, then a bar of E (dominant of A), where you could use E scale notes, leading to a bar of A, where A scale notes will work. What you need to bear in mind is that all these keys have some common notes, but they may not be chord notes. For example,all 3 have an E note, which happens to be a note from each chord triad too. So, the tune could actually stay on the one note E for all 3 bars! However, the C# for instance,really fits the A chord, not too bad over E, but awful over the C.

In the final reckoning, though, it's pointless asking anyone what'll fit. Ears usually tell the story better. If it sounds good, etc.

Incidentally, yes the A is the major 6th note of C, but this in itself has no bearing on the fact of using the A MAJOR scale. In fact, the A MINOR scale fits just about perfectly - because it's the relative minor of C.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you are just in the beginning stages of grasping music theory and that's perfectly alright.  We have all been there.

I think you might be **confusing major intervals** with **major and minor chords** that go with a given key.  It is true that the note A natural is the 6th scale degree of the C major scale (key of C).  It is also true that A natural is a "major sixth" because there are 9 semitones between the root and the 6th scale degree.  In this context the term "major sixth" refers to the interval and has nothing to do with chords in the key of C major.

**The chords used in C major** are **C Major, D minor, E minor, F Major, G Major, A minor and B diminished.**  All of these chords use notes from the C major scale.  If you played the notes from the scale corresponding to the 6 chord (vi chord) of the C major scale (which is A minor) you will be playing the same notes as the C major scale.

So in this case, as a beginner, I think you might find that it sounds best to play the notes from the scale of the sixth **chord** of the C major scale (which is A **minor**) - instead of the notes from the A major scale.

It's interesting to note that in any major key, the **six chord (vi chord)** will always be the **relative minor** of the major key and the relative minor key shares the **same notes and same key signature** as it's related major key.

Each chord in a given key will not always contain all the exact same notes as the root key (as does the vi chord discussed above), but all of the **chord tones** (notes used in the chord) will be in the root key (C major in the example).

I still refer to the chart below to help figure out which chords go with all the major keys.  I have included it here because as a beginner, you might find it particularly useful.

[image]

Have fun learning about music theory and becoming a better guitar player.

Comment: Can you suggest me a MUSIC THEORY book .

Comment: Y07 Actually most of what I know about music theory I learned here on Music Stack Exchange.  I have never read a book.  Sorry